# Grouping variables to plot multilevel bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, bar-chart

Can you please help me with the following. I have a dataset with a variable - number of products (Prod) that takes discrete values from 1 to 3 (included). Then I have a variable (Gender) 1 for males, 0 for females. I want to plot a multilevel bar chart where on the x-axis I have number of products (Prod) and on the y-axis I have total value of these products that are grouped by the Gender. I need to create a 'count' variable that counts how many observations of each 'Prod' are in each 'Gender' category.  To group and plot the variables I use the following code (which does not work):

```
#Group the variables
grouped_gender['count'] = main_data.groupby(['Prod', 'Gender'])[['Prod']].count()
grouped_gender = pd.DataFrame(grouped_gender)

#Plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 7))

barplot2 = sns.barplot(
    data=grouped_gender,
    x='Prod',
    y='count',
    hue='Gender',
    orient='v',
    ax = axes,
    ci=None,
    dodge=False
    )
```

Can you please help me to identify the problem?

Comment: Could you give a little more details? What is it that "does not work"? Do you have an error or is the result not the one you expected/wanted?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting the following error - ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Prod'

Comment: Could you maybe give the structure of the `main_data` DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can put your DataFrame in a similar state as mine

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grouped_gender = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Man": [50, 70],
        "Woman": [90, 30]
    },
    index=["Product1", "Product2"]
)

grouped_gender.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)

plt.title("Products sales")
plt.xlabel("Products")
plt.ylabel("Sales")
plt.show()
```

This produces the following result[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `countplot` on the original dataset:

```
# sample dataset
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# `day` plays `Prod`, `sex` plays `Gender`
sns.countplot(x='day', hue='sex', data=df)
```

Output:

[image]

**Note**: if you want the data, not just the plot, use:

```
counts = pd.crosstab(df['day'], df['sex'])

# then to plot bar chart
# counts.plot.bar()
```

which gives you:

```
sex   Male  Female
day               
Thur    30      32
Fri     10       9
Sat     59      28
Sun     58      18
```